# Apache Ambari not starting in hortonworks sandbox - probably 8080 is locked

Tags: port, ambari, hdp

I have HDP from hortonworks sandbox in a virtual box. My host OS is mac10.15.7.
I am getting the hortonworks Sandbox home page at localhost:1080.  However, when i try to go Ambari UI at localhost:8080 it throws error 404 as shown below

[image]

I just check to see if port 8080 is locked by some process and I get as below:

```
VirtualBo 5265 pcname 115u  IPv4 0x4b7f661b8f6c4043      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)
java      5544 pcname 46u  IPv6 0x4b7f661b88fb18b3      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

And if i kill the java process it starts again with a new PID. seems like its an Apache process. I am kind of going in circle and don't know how to get Ambari running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jio

I ran into similar before, but its been too long and I cannot locate my notes.  From what I recall, you need to use ip/hostname not localhost.  You will find info that suggest the ambari url may look like:

```
http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8080
http://127.0.0.1:8080 
http://[vm internal network ip]:8080
```

First make sure ambari is running:  ambari-server status.

Also, the sanbox is pretty big,  you may have to modify vm settings, and have a sufficient amount of resources on your main machine to fully run the sandbox + all running services.  This should not be a concern just getting logged into ambari.  This is more of a concern logging in and expecting everything to be running (all green services).

Check out this post:

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Installed-sandbox-but-can-t-get-the-welcome-HDP-page-working/m-p/102921

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Sandbox-127-0-0-1-8080-not-accessible/ta-p/244987

Comment: Thanks Steven, indeed i could access it with 127.0.0.1:8080 !